# Cannot access session variables in Laravel 4

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

My routes:

```
Route::group(array("namespace" => "languages"),function(){
   Route::resource("languagesService", "languageServiceController");
   Route::resource("languages","languageController");
});
```

languageservicecontroller and languagecontroller are in subfolder languages.

During login attempt i saved username and password in

```
Session::put('username', $user['username']);
Session::put('password', $user['password']);
```

But when i try to retrieve from languageController

```
$username = Session::get('username');
$password = Session::get('password');
```

i am getting following error

> "Class 'languages\Session' not found" .

Comment: Do you have a namespace in your controller?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are trying to access the `Session` class from a namespace where the `Session` class does not exist.

**Try the following:**

```
\Session::get('password')
```

**OR**

Include `Session` class at the top of your file.

```
<?php namespace languages;

use Session;


class languageServiceController
{

}
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. if namespace used, all the core functionality of the controller need to be called again?. i am bit unclear about the namespace in laravel. Plz provide me with the link that best explains it, if u know

Comment: @uma, have a look the following link. http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.rationale.php

Answer (score 0):

IF your using Sentry to handle the User sessions it should be

```
 $user = Sentry::getUser();

        if ( isset($user) )
        {  $username = Helpers::loggedInUser()->username;
```